# Notepad++ YYYY to YY

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have `22/01/2010` however I want it to be `22/01/10`.

At the moment I use `([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})` to find. But need help with the replace regex.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're so close. Replace

```
([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/[0-9]{2}([0-9]{2})
```

with

```
$1/$2/$3
```

You can of course simplify this by replacing

```
([0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/)[0-9]{2}([0-9]{2})
```

with

```
$1$2
```

but arguably the former is more readable.

Answer (score 2):

or just replace this regex:

```
(?<=\d{2}/\d{2}/)\d{2}(?=\d{2})
```

or shorter:

```
(?<=\d\d/\d\d/)\d\d(?=\d\d)
```

with empty string.

The advantage is....... you don't need type anything in your replace With box. :D

Comment: @ridgerunner I thought the same too, but ... it depends.... who knows how does OP's text look like? e.g. `"Today _05/22/2013_ I answered a question"`

Answer (score 0):

Find: `([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})`

Replace: `\1/\2/\4`